# Event calendar not showing February

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I am creating an events calendar for my website and I have used [this tutorial](http://dinocaspero.blogspot.co.uk/search?q=tutorial) and [this other one](http://unknownghost03.blogspot.co.uk/p/tutorials-source-code.html), as well as the youtube tutorial by unknown ghost.

However, when I enter an event, it comes up as successful but doesn't turn blue.

1. Have I made an error/typo that could explain why it isn't turning blue?
2. Also once an event has been added, it does display at the bottom but if I refresh the page the event gets added again automatically.
3. Went through each month and realised February doesn't come up. Why is this?

Here is my code:

***calendar.php***

```
<?php 
include("functions.php")
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Event Calendar</title>
  <script>
   function goLastMonth(month, year){
    if(month == 1) {
     --year;
     month = 13;
    }
    --month
    var monthstring = ""+month+"";
    var monthlength = monthstring.length;
    if(monthlength <=1){
     monthstring = "0"+monthstring;
    }
    document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year;
   }
   function goNextMonth(month, year){
    if(month == 12) {
     ++year;
     month = 0;
    }
    ++month
    var monthstring = ""+month+"";
    var monthlength = monthstring.length;
    if(monthlength <=1){
     monthstring = "0"+monthstring;
    }
    document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?month="+monthstring+"&year="+year;
   }
  </script>
  <style>
    .today{
      background-color: #00ff00;
    }
    .event{
      background-color: #0000ff;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>

  <?php
   //get current date or specific month and year
   if (isset($_GET['day'])){
    $day = $_GET['day'];
   } else {
    $day = date("d");
   }
   if(isset($_GET['month'])){
    $month = $_GET['month'];
   } else {
    $month = date("m");
   }
   if(isset($_GET['year'])){
    $year = $_GET['year'];
   }else{
    $year = date("Y");
   }

   //get date data for display such as month name
   $currentTimeStamp = strtotime( "$day-$month-$year");
   $monthName = date("F", $currentTimeStamp);
   //get the number of days in the current month and year
   $numDays = date("t", $currentTimeStamp);
   //keep track of the number of cell created
   $counter = 0;  
   ?>
   <?php
   if(isset($_GET['add'])) {
       $name = $_POST['Event_Name'];
       $details = $_POST['Details'];
       $date = $day."/".$month."/".$year;
       $location = $_POST['Location'];
       $staffrq = $_POST['Staff_Required'];
       $cadetsrq = $_POST['Cadets_Required'];
      //insert into database
       $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO Event_Detail (Event_Name, Details, Date, Location, Staff_Required, Cadets_Required) VALUES 
       ('".$name."', '".$details."', '".$date."', '".$location."', '".$staffrq."','".$cadetsrq."')";
       $resultinsert = mysql_query($sqlinsert);
       if($resultinsert) {
         echo "Event Successfully Added...";
       }else{
         echo "Event Failed to be Added...";
       }
     }
  ?>

  <table border="1px">
   <tr>
    <td align="center">
     <input style='width:80px;' type='button' value='<'name='previousbutton' onclick ="goLastMonth(<?php echo $month.','.$year?>)">
    </td>
    <td align="center" colspan="5"><?php echo $monthName." ".$year; ?></td>
    <td align="center">
     <input style='width:80px;' type='button' value='>'name='nextbutton' onclick ="goNextMonth(<?php echo $month.','.$year?>)">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center" width='80px'>Monday</td>
    <td align="center" width='80px'>Tuesday</td>
    <td align="center" width='80px'>Wednesday</td>
    <td align="center" width='80px'>Thursday</td>
    <td align="center" width='80px'>Friday</td>
    <td align="center" width='80px'>Saturday</td>
    <td align="center" width='80px'>Sunday</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align="center">

     <?php
          for($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++, $counter++){
      $timeStamp = strtotime("$i-$month-$year");

      //create empty cell until first day of the month
      if($i == 1) {
       //0=sun, 1=mon, 2=tue, ...
       $firstDay = date("w", $timeStamp);

       //if sunday change the firstDay to 7
       if($firstDay == 0)
       $firstDay = 7;

       //decrement firstDay by 1
       $firstDay--;

       for($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++) {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
       }
      }

      //create new row
      if($counter % 7 == 0) {
       echo"</tr><tr>";
      }
      $monthstring = $month;
      $monthlength = strlen($monthstring);
      $daystring = $i;
      $daylength = strlen($daystring);
      if($monthlength <=1){
        $monthstring = "0".$monthstring;
      }
      if($daylength <=1) {
        $daystring = "0".$daystring;
      }
      $todaysDate = date("d/m/Y");
      $dateToCompare = $daystring.'/'.$monthstring.'/'.$year;
      //print day number
      echo "<td align='center'";
      if ($todaysDate == $dateToCompare) {
        echo "class='today'";
      }else{
        $sqlCount = "SELECT * FROM Event_Detail WHERE Date='".$dateToCompare."'";
        $noOfEvent = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sqlCount));
        if($noOfEvents >=1) {
          echo "class='event'";
        }
      }
      echo "><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?day=".$daystring."&month=".$monthstring."&year=".$year."&v=true'>".$i."</a></td>";
     }


     //fill up the leftover cells of the table
     while($counter % 7 != 0) {
      echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
      $counter++;
     }
    ?>
   </tr>
  </table>

     <?php
     if(isset($_GET['v'])){
       echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?day=".$day."&month=".$month."&year=".$year."&v=true&f=true'>Add Event</a>";
       if(isset($_GET['f'])){
         include("eventform.php");
       }
       $sqlEvent = "SELECT * FROM Event_Detail WHERE Date='".$day."/".$month."/".$year."'";
       $resultEvents=mysql_query($sqlEvent);
       echo "<hr>";
       while($events=mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
         echo "Event Name: ".$events['Event_Name']."<br>";
         echo "Details: ".$events['Details']."<br>";
         echo "Date: ".$events['Date']."<br>";
         echo "Location: ".$events['Location']."<br>";
         echo "Staff Required: ".$events['Staff_Required']."<br>";
         echo "Cadets Required: ".$events['Cadets_Required']."<br>";
       }
     }
     ?>
     </body>
</html>
```

***eventform.php***

```
<title>Event</title>
 <form name="eventform" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?  >?day=<?php echo $day;?>&month=<?php echo $month;?>&year=<?php echo $year;? >&v=true&add=true">
  <table width="400px">
   <tr>
  <td width="150px">Event Name</td>
  <td width="250px"><input type="text" name="Event_Name" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="150px">Details</td>
  <td width="250px"><textarea name="Details" required></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width='150px'>Location</td>
  <td width='250px'><textarea name="Location" required></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width='150px'>Staff Required</td>
  <td width='250px'><input type='number' name="Staff_Required" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width='150px'>Cadets Required</td>
  <td width='50px'><input type='number' name="Cadets_Required" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan='2' align='center'><input type='submit' name='btnadd' value='Add Event'></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @vard thank you for editing

Comment: I found out why it wasn't turning blue. when declaring the variable and using it ($noOfEvent) i made a typo and wrote $noOfEvents